# Email Value From Variable & Hyperlink

Tags: email, powershell

From within PowerShell, I know how to send a basic email.  But with my syntax below, how could I append to the body of the email each `$QueryName` and each `$RowCount` and add a hyperlink to the value contained in `$FPath\$FormattedDate\`so the body of email would look like this:

```
$QueryName - $RowCount
```

(or with actual data)

```
Santa - 14
Mickey - 12
Mars - 2
```

Here is my current PS script

```psh
Function Execute-SQLquery {
param ($QueryName, $QueryString)

$server = "Server"
$database = "DB1"
$FPath = "C:\Testing"

#Setting additional variables
$extension = ".csv" 
$date = Get-Date -f 'MM.dd.yy'
$FormattedDate = Get-Date -f 'MM.dd.yy'

$connectionTemplate = "Data Source={0};Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog={1};"
$connectionString = [string]::Format($connectionTemplate, $server, $database)
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString

$command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$command.CommandText = $QueryString
$command.Connection = $connection

$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $command
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$rowCount = $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)

if(!(Test-Path -path "$FPath\$FormattedDate\")){New-Item "$FPath\$FormattedDate\" -type directory}

if ($rowCount -gt 0)
{
    if ($QueryName -eq "Santa")
    {
        $extractFile = "C:\Testing\TemplateFiles\Santa.csv"
        [System.IO.Directory]::CreateDirectory("$FPath\$FormattedDate\Santa\")
        Write-Host $rowCount -fore Red
        $dirName = "$FPath\$FormattedDate\Santa\"
        $filename = [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($extractFile) + "_$date" + [IO.Path]::GetExtension($extractFile)
        $extractFile = Join-Path $dirname $filename
    }
    if ($QueryName -eq "Mickey")
    {
        $extractFile = "C:\Testing\TemplateFiles\Mickey.csv"
        [System.IO.Directory]::CreateDirectory("$FPath\$FormattedDate\Mickey\")
        Write-Host $rowCount -fore Red
        $dirName = "$FPath\$FormattedDate\Mickey\"
        $filename = [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($extractFile) + "_$date" + [IO.Path]::GetExtension($extractFile)
        $extractFile = Join-Path $dirname $filename
    }
    if ($QueryName -eq "Mars")
    {
        $extractFile = "C:\Testing\TemplateFiles\Mickey\Mars.csv"
        [System.IO.Directory]::CreateDirectory("$FPath\$FormattedDate\Mars\")
        Write-Host $rowCount -fore Red
        $dirName = "$FPath\$FormattedDate\Mars\"
        $filename = [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($extractFile) + "_$date" + [IO.Path]::GetExtension($extractFile)
        $extractFile = Join-Path $dirname $filename
    }
    $DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-Csv $extractFile -NoTypeInformation
} 
$connection.Close()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up, since the only thing that changes based on `$QueryName` are direct references to the value in `$QueryName` and the `$extractFile`, you'd be better off not repeating that entire block.

For the mail message, you can use [`Send-MailMessage`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849925.aspx).

To add a link to a local file resource, use the `file:///` scheme prefix and change all backslashes (`\`) to forward slashes (`/`), ie. `file:///C:/Document/Path.ext`, or in your example `"file:///$("$FPath\$FormattedDate" -replace '\','/')"`:

```psh
Function Execute-SQLquery {
    param ($QueryName, $QueryString)

    # up to this point no change is required

    if ($rowCount -gt 0)
    {
        $extractFile = switch($QueryName){
            "Santa"  { "C:\Testing\TemplateFiles\Santa.csv" }
            "Mickey" { "C:\Testing\TemplateFiles\Mickey.csv" }
            "Mars"   { "C:\Testing\TemplateFiles\Mars\Mickey.csv" }
            default  { throw "Illegal QueryName" }
        }

        [System.IO.Directory]::CreateDirectory("$FPath\$FormattedDate\$QueryName\")
        Write-Host $rowCount -fore Red
        $dirName = "$FPath\$FormattedDate\$QueryName\"
        $filename = [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($extractFile) + "_$date" + [IO.Path]::GetExtension($extractFile)
        $extractFile = Join-Path $dirname $filename

        $DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-Csv $extractFile -NoTypeInformation

        $EmailBody = @'
Here are the results:

{0} - {1}

Find the documents <a href="file:///{2}">here</a>
'@ -f $QueryName,$rowCount,$("$FPath\$FormattedDate" -replace '\','/')

        Send-MailMessage -From "me@company.example" -To "you@company.example" -Body $EmailBody -BodyAsHtml:$true -Subject "Data extracted!" -SmtpServer "your.mail.server.company.example"
    } 
    $connection.Close()
}
```

Comment: That throws an error when I try to execute.  'White space is not allowed before the string terminator.  Missing closing ')' in statement block

Comment: @BigPimpin As the error says, no whitespace is allowed before the `'@` part of the `$EmailBody` here-string. I know it looks awkward without indentation, but as you can see, there's a reason for this

Comment: this sends an individual email for all 3 extract files.  Is it possible to send 1 email showing cumulative information for all 3 extract files?